# Create textbox within Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to create a textbox so as to input a variable and later use that value within the script. I know there is a getValue() option, but it has not been working so far.

```js
var lon = ui.Textbox({
  value: 0,
  placeholder: 'Enter rise level here...',
  onChange: function(value) {
    // set value with a dedicated method
    lon.setValue(value);
    return(value);
  }
});
Map.add(lon)
var Lo;
var button = ui.Button({
  label: 'Set rise level',
  onClick: function() {
    // you don't have to convert it into EE objects since you are
    // working on the client side
    Lo = parseFloat(lon.getValue());
    print(Lo)
    var image = ee.Image(Lo)
    Map.addLayer(image,{},'',0)
  }
});
Map.add(button)
```

Comment: Please share what you have so far.

Comment: Shared, thanks for commenting

Comment: Your current code works. When you press the button "Set rise level", it gets the value from the "lon" TextBox, prints this value into the console, and adds a new layer which is an ee.Image with the constant value retrieved from the Text box. The name of the layer is empty, and you don't remove it, so any time the button is pressed a new layer is added (always with an empty name). Could you please clarify why you think `getValue()`  is not working? what do you want the app to do?

Comment: I actually don't need the image to be created, just added it to check if the script works, I just need to pass this value onto the script for further development of the code. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you just need to call the `.getValue()` method from the ui.Textbox (which you called `lon`) where you want to use it.  Your current code already demonstrated how it works.

Comment: Does it work outside of the function?